# Discord.py doesn't update on member remove

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that changes a voice channels' name when a user joins or leaves to the amount of members on the server. My issue is that when a user leaves, it doesn't update. Any help is appreciated.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_member_remove(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=973603264639668248)
    await channel.edit(name=f'Member Count: {member.guild.member_count}')
```

Comment: Also make sure that the GUILD_MEMBERS. is also enabled in your bot application

Answer (score 2):

The right event for this would be [on_member_remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_remove#discord.on_member_remove).

You can also get the channel in a much easier way and edit it.

**See a possible new code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member: discord.Member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(Channel_ID_here)
    await channel.edit(name=f"Member Count: {len(member.guild.members)}")
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are using  `on_raw_member_remove`
You should be using `on_member_leave` as the member is not getting removed.